# Pandas does not change categorical data [sex] to numerical values [0/1]

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, categorical-data, kaggle

I am trying to work through the Titanic dataset.  I want to convert the `Sex` column to binary values.  This is my attempt:

```
sex = train_dataset['Sex'].replace([0,1],['female','male'],inplace=True)
```

And when I try to `print(sex)`, the console outputs `None`!

I have tried to implement other approaches on SO as well but none of them seem to work.  Below is my full source code:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import corrcoef

train_dataset = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test_dataset = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/test.csv")

survived = train_dataset['Survived']
pClass = train_dataset['Pclass']

#Doesn't work
sex = train_dataset['Sex'].replace([0,1],['female','male'],inplace=True)

age = train_dataset['Age']
fare = train_dataset['Fare']
parch = train_dataset['Parch']
sibSp = train_dataset['SibSp']

# print("Correlation between parent-children & survival is: " + str(corrcoef(survived, parch)))
# print("Correlation between age & survival is: " + str(corrcoef(survived, age)))
# print("Correlation between Siblings/Spouse & survival is: " + str(corrcoef(survived, sibSp)))

print(sex)
```

Comment: You are using the option `inplace=True`, This changes the `train_dataset` instance, instead of returning a value. Now that you know that no value is returned when using `inplace=True`, you will understand that `sex` should be equal to `None`, because nothing is returned

Comment: Thanks @KenHBS I've noticed it just before Richard posted his answer.  I appreciate your help nonetheless.  Ive upvoted your comment.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sex = train_dataset['Sex'].replace(['female','male'],[0,1])
print(sex)
```

It looks like your syntax is off. See the [replace function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace)

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation for the parameters:

> inplace : bool, default False If True, in place. Note: this will
>   modify any other views on this object (e.g. a column from a
>   DataFrame). Returns the caller if this is True.

To summarize, `inplace=True` returns `None` and `inplace=False` returns a copy of the object with the operation performed.

So, in your case as the operation is `inplace=True`, the original series object `train_dataset['Sex']` is modified. Try to print the `train_dataset` after the operation, you should see the modified dataframe.

Refer to the official documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here, first, you have turned around the arguments in `.replace(<replace_this>, <with_this>)`. Secondly, you are using the option `inplace=True`. This changes the `train_dataset` instance, instead of returning a value.

Now that you know that no value is returned when using `inplace=True`, you will understand that `sex` should be equal to `None`, because nothing is returned:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'male']})
>>> df
        a
# 0    male
# 1  female
# 2  female
# 3    male
```

### Without `replace=True`:

Now when we replace the values, we'd get

```
>>> df.replace(['female', 'male'], [0,1])
# a
# 0  1
# 1  0
# 2  0
# 3  1
```

But `df` itself still looks exactly the same as it did before:

```
>>> df
        a
#  0    male
#  1  female
#  2  female
#  3    male
```

So in order to replace the value in `df`, we would do:

```
>>> df['a'] = df['a'].replace(['male', 'female'], [0,1])
>>> df
#    a
# 0  0
# 1  1
# 2  1
# 3  0
```

## With `replace=True`:

When you run this instead: `df.replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1], inplace=True))`, you would get a manipulated version of `df` back right away:

```
>>> df.replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1], inplace=True)
>>> df
#    a
# 0  0
# 1  1
# 2  1
# 3  0
```

Note that `inplace=True` argument makes that no value is returned:

```
>>> test = df.replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1], inplace=True)
>>> type(test)
# <class 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where`

```
dataset['sex']=np.where(dataset['sex']=='female',0,1)
```

Comment: How come you don't check for `dataset['sex']=='male'`?

Comment: male gets assigned a 1 by default.  You could have it the way way too np.where(dataset['sex']=='male',1,0) should also work and produce the same output.

Comment: Ah okay.  Makes sense.  Unfortunately I've already accepted Richard's answer but I did upvote you nonetheless out of appreciation for your effort.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: you can give this a shot too(same logic actually ;) )`train_dataset['Sex'].eq('male').astype(int)` @oo92